# How to link slack user with github account?

Tags: oauth-2.0, github-api, slack, slack-api

I am creating a slack bot and want to be able to link the slack user with the github account.

Is there a way I can link the 2 either via slack or github API's?

I was thinking if of storing users slack username and github username in a JSON object, i.e.:

```
{
    "slack_username": "JoeBlogs",
    "github_username": "JoeBlogs123"
}
```

In order to do this, I would need to retrieve the users' username from slack API when the user authorises the app / bot.

I was thinking if I add a `redirect_url` to my slack app then it would redirect user to `http://example.com/redirect` if the users data is sent along to this redirect url, I would be able save it in a database of sorts.

If I then did the same with the github API then I could reference database in order to find slack users `JoeBlogs` github account and vice versa.

Is it possible to use the `redirect_url` like this? I couldn't see any user data being sent to but maybe it is nested somewhere I couldn't see it?

Is there a better way to link the 2 accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Install button to install your Slack app into the workspace, this is a payload which will be sent to your `response_url`:

```
{
    "access_token": "xoxp-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
    "scope": "incoming-webhook,commands,bot",
    "team_name": "Team Installing Your Hook",
    "team_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "incoming_webhook": {
        "url": "https://hooks.slack.com/TXXXXX/BXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX",
        "channel": "#channel-it-will-post-to",
        "configuration_url": "https://teamname.slack.com/services/BXXXXX"
    },
    "bot":{
        "bot_user_id":"UTTTTTTTTTTR",
        "bot_access_token":"xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXX-TTTTTTTTTTTTTT"
    }
}
```

[See for details.](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button#request_a_token)

Then, using `access_token` in combination with [users.identity](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.identity) API method you will get basic information about Slack user (playing with the scopes you requested during the install process you can get different fields of Slack user identity).